# Caret - tuning: Models' default parameters

Tags: r, machine-learning, parameters, r-caret

I can't find a list of the **default** machine learning models' parameters for the tuning search space. I know that it's possible to retrieve the grid values searching manually them on the [github page](https://github.com/topepo/caret/tree/master/models/files), but I don't think this is the right way. I need these parameters because I'm trying to do an execution time estimate for all the classification models on the default configuration. I'm unable to find them on the [caret documentation](https://topepo.github.io/caret/train-models-by-tag.html). Is there a way to retrieve them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`modelLookup()` is what you need. This will return per model the parameters you can tune.

```
models <- modelLookup()
head(models)

     model parameter          label forReg forClass probModel
1      ada      iter         #Trees  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
2      ada  maxdepth Max Tree Depth  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
3      ada        nu  Learning Rate  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
4   AdaBag    mfinal         #Trees  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
5   AdaBag  maxdepth Max Tree Depth  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
9 adaboost     nIter         #Trees  FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
```

filter on forClass to get the models for classification only.

Comment: but for the parameters default search range? Is there a way to find them?

Comment: getModelInfo() will return a large list with all the options, including grid. But there are no default grid values. everything is based on formula's, samples, no records and or columns in data.frame etc etc. There are no fixed rules.